# Python argparse if action true then check other condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

Is there easy way if action is true then check other arguments else ignore it.

Example:

```
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('testing.')
   parser.add_argument('-P', '--parallel', help='run parallely in all', action='store_true')
   parser.add_argument('-t','--testing', help='check only if -P argument passed', required=True)
```

If -P argument passed, then -t argument is needed otherwise ignore to check.